# What are the best backup tools around that someone should consider before making a decision?

Tags: backup

I've found [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/) and [Amanda](http://amanda.zmanda.com/), but are there other nice backup tools out there?
I'm sure some exist but I haven't found them yet.

Can we make a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about making a larger post to go into community wiki so it can hit 1st on google for people needing a list of all the best backup tools as such, but it seems noone will cooperate :(

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements. We needed a cheap way to backup about 100 small MSSQL databases on an hourly basis totaling around 1GB for full backups or 100MB for differentials when compressed. We also had to use strong encryption to meet HIPAA compliance and needed to make sure that any issues were logged and that alerts were sent to support staff. Rather than finding a 3rd party tool we just decided to write a Powershell script that uses [7-zip and Amazon S3](http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/02/powershell-7-zip-amazon-s3-upload.html) to store the hourly backups with 1 month retention for less than $10 a month. This script runs as a SQL Job, so our monitoring software will notify us if there are any issues. This fits our needs very well, but if you have 100s of GB of data or want tools to help restore individual files then one of the online backup services would probably work much better.